# Material not working properly in model

Tags: modeling, rendering

I made sword model in blender. I attached material to blade of it. But material not rendering properly. [image]

I searched for problem. But google can't find right solution.

How can i fix it?

[image]
This is my project.

[image]

This is what i am talking about.

Comment: Hello what do you mean it doesn't render properly? Maybe share your file

Comment: That is straigh line starting of blade.

git@github.com:komiljonov/3dModels.git

This is link to file.

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure what the url is supposed to be?

Comment: Share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ if possible with any material files packed into the Blend file. Follow the instructions on that web page to copy the link and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @ShukurulloxKomiljonov Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded and put link to my post on top.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, what straight line are you talking about? Maybe show a picture that hightlights the problem? Also note that you have overlapping vertices, select all in Edit mode and press M >Merge by Distance

Comment: I attachched one more image to post.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped the blade and then scaled it in the UV editor? - Also that material file has a series of squares on it that show up on the blade which rather spoil the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John points out, it's a problem of UV unwrapping, as you see, the part you're showing is not unwrapped like the rest:

[image]

[image]

A quick fix could be to select the whole blade, choose the front view, unwrap with the *Project from View* method, scale and rotate the UV 90° in the *UV Editor*, and it will give about the same as what you have currently:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you it helped to me.